# Uploaded file to Google Docs doesn't show up

Tags: android, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload a file to Google Docs/Drive using Documents List API on Android.

The problem is that it seems to be OK (I get status code 200, OK), but the file doesn't show up when looking at my documents. Uploading to this address that I get when listing the feeds: https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full?convert=false

I've tried several ways, but w/o any luck for example:

```
File file = new File(sFile); // Path to the file on the SD card

InputStreamContent content = new InputStreamContent("application/vnd.mymimetype",
                    new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));

content.setLength(file.length());
HttpRequest request = transport.createRequestFactory().buildPostRequest(new GoogleUrl(sURL), content); // Urls is https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full?convert=false

GoogleHeaders headers = getDefaultHeaders(); // Set version 3 and authentication

request.setHeaders(headers);
res = request.execute(); // Will have status code 200, not 201 as created and no entity returned?
```

I've also tried with MediaUploader, but same result (In this example, I set metadata, but I think I get an exception that Content Lenght isn't set, so in my working example, I don't set meta data):

```
StringBuilder sAtom = new StringBuilder()
                    .append("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>")
                    .append("<entry xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\" xmlns:docs=\"http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007\">")
                    .append("<title>THeFile</title>").append("</entry>");
 String sCmd = sAtom.toString();
 InputStream inStream = null;

 inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(sCmd.getBytes("UTF-8"));

 final InputStreamContent oContent = new InputStreamContent("application/atom+xml", inStream);
 oContent.setLength(sCmd.length());

 InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("application/vnd.mymimetype",
                    new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
 mediaContent.setLength(file.length());

 MediaHttpUploader uploader = new MediaHttpUploader(mediaContent, transport, new HttpRequestInitializer() {

                @Override
                public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                    GoogleHeaders headers = getDefaultHeaders();
                    headers.setSlug("thefile.mab");
                    request.setHeaders(headers);
                }
            });
 uploader.setMetadata(oContent);

 MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener listner = new CustomProgressListener();
 uploader.setProgressListener(listner);
 uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(true);

 HttpResponse response = uploader.upload(new GoogleUrl(sURL));
 if (!response.isSuccessStatusCode()) { // Gets that the upload was successful
            throw new Exception("Error");
 }
```

What am I missing?? :/

Comment: Are you sure that the file is not being uploaded. Sometimes it might not appear on the main Google Drive feed in the UI. Could you try using the name of the file and search for it using the search box just to make sure?

Comment: hi, could you please tell me the libraries that which used for this code? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, that you have. And it appears, that MediaHttpUploader don't have valid headers set up.

Here code that works for me

```
GoogleUrl url = new GoogleUrl("resumable upload link ");

GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
headers.setSlugFromFileName("my image.jpg");
headers.set("X-Upload-Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
headers.set("X-Upload-Content-Length", content.getLength());
//without this I got the same error
headers.gdataVersion = "3";

MediaHttpUploader uploader = new MediaHttpUploader(content, getTransport(), getRequestFactory().getInitializer());
uploader.setInitiationMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
uploader.setInitiationHeaders(headers);
uploader.upload(url);
```

Comment: Hi, could you please tell me the libraries that which used for this code??? Thanks...

Comment: I've been using google-api-client (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) version 1.7.0 beta. Some methods can be different in more risent versions of google-api-client.